# Book that explained different forms of time travel in films

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, time

I remember a while back reading a book about the different forms of time travel in movies and science fiction. I can't seem to recall the name now!

Comment: Was it one of Paul J. Nahin's book on [Time Machines](http://www.amazon.com/Time-Machines-Physics-Metaphysics-Science/dp/0387985719) and [Time Travel](http://www.amazon.com/Time-Travel-Writers-Science-Plausible/dp/1421400820)?

Comment: I've removed the general request for recommendations since that was drawing the question off topic

Answer (score 3):

Here's the Library O' Congress catalogue stuff:

**Nahin, Paul J.  *Time Machines: time travel in physics, metaphysics, and science fiction* (2nd ed).  NYC: Springer-Verlag (1998).  ISBN 0-387-98571-9.**

Throughout the book are hundreds of examples of time travel in various media of Sci-Fi.  Similar premises and stories are compared and examined with various prevailing and even a few of the more fringe viewpoints; all with a rigorous mathematical framework but not overbearingly so on the reader.
On the whole, the subtitle says it all:  it examines both the physics, the metaphysics, and the cultural phenomenon that is time travel.

It is also probably a decent enough reference for anyone who wants to tackle some of the unanswered [story-identifcation](/questions/tagged/story-identifcation)[time-travel](/questions/tagged/time-travel) questions here.

Comment: A newer book by this author, perhaps a re-titled new edition of the one mentioned here, is [Time Machine Tales](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319488622).